# Edge coloring graphs is in P?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, graph-colorings

It is known that there exist polynomial time algorithm to approximate the [Lovasz number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_number) or the supremum of Shannon capacity of graphs.

By Vizing's theorem, the graph $G$ has only two chromatic indices-either its maximum degree (in which case the line graph of $G$ may be perfect), or one more than it (in which case, the line graph is definitely not perfect). Then, by approximately calculating the lovasz number of the jump graph of $G$ (complement of the line graph of $G$), and, then using the Lovasz sandwich theorem, it must be possible to determine the chromatic index right?  Then does this imply that edge coloring is in P( or at least, can approximated in P)? What am I missing here? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Not an answer but a meta-comment: If finding a proper edge-coloring that uses the minimum possible number of colors were known to be in P, wouldn't that he in the literature? Surely this is a problem that had garnered a lot of attention.

Comment: @Mike that is what is troubling me.

Comment: @Mike just for some diversion, the Tardos Function(related to the Lovasz number) was actually used to provide a counterexample to a purported proof which proposed $P\neq NP$. See [here](https://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/2017/08/15/on-norbert-blums-claimed-proof-that-p-does-not-equal-np/)

Comment: I will have to take a look. But implicit in my comments was the assumption '"if $P \not = NP$"

Answer (score 3):

Holyer proved that the edge-coloring (chromatic index) of a graph is an NP-complete problem, even for cubic graphs: https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0210055.

So if $P\neq NP$, the best approximation of the chromatic index in polynomial time is the one given by Vizing's theorem: $\Delta(G)$ or $\Delta(G)+1$.

**Edit: (connection with the Lovász number)**

The Lovász number of the complement of a graph is "sandwiched" between its clique number and its chromatic number. So if $H$ is a line graph of $G$ and $\omega(H)\ge 4$, then $\omega(H)=\Delta(G)\le \chi(H) \le \Delta(G)+1$ and $\omega(H)\le \theta(\bar{H})\le\chi(H)$. Now even if we know $\theta(\bar{H})$ precisely, we cannot always determine $\chi(H)$, because we can have $\theta(\bar{H})=\Delta(G)$ and in this case $\chi(H)$ can attain both values $\Delta(G)$ and $\Delta(G)+1$.

Comment: Right, but this doesn't answer the question. The question asks why a particular approach doesn't work, which is not the same as asking why we think it is too good to be true.

Comment: So you mean to say that it is just as easy as saying that verify the line graph coloring with $\Delta$ colors, which can be done in polynomial time- so this gives us the chromatic index-if the $\Delta$ coloring fails-it is class $2$, if it works- it is class $1$. Right?